# Row_number and wrapping select ?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have this code :

`Select name, age , row_number() over (partition by name order by age desc) rn from my table`

*(goal : select the oldest guy among same names)*

If I want to select all the row numbered records which is `1` ,I guess I must do :

`Select ... from ( above query) where rn=1`

But this  force me to wrap it with another `select`.

Is there any other solution instead of wrapping in `select` ?  (cte is also like wrapping)

Comment: I mean why wrapping it another select is a problem?

Comment: @ypercube not a problem , Just want to expand my knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't *generally* possible but is in the specific case in your question.

Windowed functions are allowed only in steps 5.1 and 6 in the [Logical Query Processing flow chart here](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf) (The `SELECT` and `ORDER BY`).

`SELECT` cannot be used to reduce the returned rows. In SQL Server 2008 `ORDER BY` can only do so in conjunction with `TOP` (For 2012 `OFFSET ... FETCH` can filter on the basis of `ORDER`). As you are only interested in ones where the `ROW_NUMBER` expression evaluates to `1` in this case you can use

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES name,
                         age
FROM   mytable
ORDER  BY row_number() OVER (partition BY name ORDER BY age DESC)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eede0/1)

Following discussion in the comments about how this could be extended to get the `TOP 2` per partition. This would be *possible*

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES name,
                         age
FROM   mytable
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN row_number() OVER (partition BY name ORDER BY age DESC) <= 2 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
          END
```

I personally wouldn't use either of the queries in this answer though. I would just wrap the query in a table expression and filter using `WHERE`.