# Using IN clause in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, greatest-n-per-group

I am using the below command to get the result at once in one command, but this does not give me two rows output where as it selects only one top row even if use "IN" clause.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM [DBName].[XY].[Tablename] 
where [Domain] IN ('US','IN') 
ORDER BY [CreateDate] DESC
```

Instead I have to use two separate commands to get the desired result. Please correct me.

I want one row, the most recent one, from each `Domain`.

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM [DBName].[XY].[Tablename] 
where [Domain]='US' 
ORDER BY [CreateDate] DESC

SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM [DBName].[XY].[Tablename] 
where [Domain]='IN' 
ORDER BY [CreateDate] DESC
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Row\_number and wrapping select ?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33005/row-number-and-wrapping-select)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  *

from   (SELECT  *
               ,row_number () over (partition by [Domain] order by [CreateDate] DESC) as rn
        FROM    [DBName].[XY].[Tablename] 
        where   [Domain] IN ('US','IN')
        ) t

where   rn = 1
```